# File Ownership changes to root after saving from a program in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webstorm

I've a file and the owner is me (userx). I opened the file with a program WebStorm.sh (sudo sh webstorm.sh). When I save the file, the owner of the file changes to root.

I do not want this program (webstorm) to change the owner of the file. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? Seems legit.

Comment: Any way to get an 'accepted' answer to this?

Answer (score 7):

It's not webstorm, it's the fact that you're running as root (sudo).  Stop doing that and the owner information won't change.

Comment: In some cases I need to run WS as sudo, do you know how to handle it

Comment: @KoboldMines - none that I'm aware of in any flavor or *nix